# WMI and VBScript

Tags: vbscript

Edit of original post after many attempts to correct script.  Last script as per Symantec  still does not fix issue with a pc with TPM not enabled in the bios.  Script does not output what was/now is in the if/else statement. There is output for a pc with TPM enabled  and nothing for a pc where it is not enabled. All references to Altiris server and writing to db removed.  This is just now testing the script itself.

```
On Error Resume Next
strComputer = "."
Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer &    "\root\CIMV2    \Security\MicrosoftTpm")

If Err.number <> 0 Then
WScript.Echo "Error connecting to: " & strComputer
WScript.Echo "Setting Not Applicable when necessary"
Else
Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Tpm", "WQL",     wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)

If Err.number <> 0 Then
WScript.Echo "Another Error"
End If

For each objInfo in colItems

WScript.Echo objInfo.IsActivated_InitialValue
WScript.Echo objInfo.IsEnabled_InitialValue
WScript.Echo objInfo.IsOwned_InitialValue
WScript.Echo objInfo.ManufacturerId
WScript.Echo objInfo.ManufacturerVersion
WScript.Echo objInfo.ManufacturerVersionInfo
WScript.Echo objInfo.PhysicalPresenceVersionInfo
WScript.Echo objInfo.SpecVersion
Next
End If
```

Comment: I [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.
But you still may need to add further information for your question to become fully solvable.

Answer (score 0):

Edited: Changed answer to match edited question.  Removal of Altiris code.

Hey, I would use the following script to get the information you need.  This will ignore errors when attempting to get TPM information through WMI.  Since the `Win32_Tpm` class is a singleton class, it can only have one instance (The WMI name for results in the class).  You'll notice that is indicated using `Win32_Tpm=@`.  When that code is used after the class name it means return  the one and only instance from this class.  When you do that, you no longer need a `For..Next` loop because there can only ever be one object returned.

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim TPMProvider : Set TPMProvider = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2\Security\MicrosoftTpm:Win32_Tpm=@")
Wscript.Echo "Error: " & Err.number
On Error Goto 0 'This is optional and turns errors back on

Wscript.Echo "VarType: " & VarType(TPMProvider)

If VarType(TPMProvider) <> 9 Then
    WScript.Echo "Setting Not Applicable when necessary"
Else
    WScript.Echo TPMProvider.IsActivated_InitialValue
    WScript.Echo TPMProvider.IsEnabled_InitialValue
    WScript.Echo TPMProvider.IsOwned_InitialValue
    WScript.Echo TPMProvider.ManufacturerId
    WScript.Echo TPMProvider.ManufacturerVersion
    WScript.Echo TPMProvider.ManufacturerVersionInfo
    WScript.Echo TPMProvider.PhysicalPresenceVersionInfo
    WScript.Echo TPMProvider.SpecVersion
End If
```

Some additional information that could help you are the err.number results that would most likely appear and what those errors mean.

**WMI Error Codes** (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wmi-error-constants)

- -2147217405 = WBEM_E_ACCESS_DENIED - Access Denied: Current user does not have permission to perform the action.
- -2147217406 = WBEM_E_NOT_FOUND - Object cannot be found
- -2147217394 = WBEM_E_INVALID_NAMESPACE - Namespace specified cannot be found.
- -2147217392 = WBEM_E_INVALID_CLASS - Specified class is not valid
- -2147217375 = WBEM_E_INVALID_SYNTAX - Query is syntactically not valid

You'll also notice that i'm using VarType in the script.  That is to detect what type of data the TPMProvider variable is.  We want it to be an "object type" (number 9) in order to continue because thats what a successful WMI object would appear as.  If the VarType is 0 or 1 then setting the variable was unsuccessful.

**VarType Function** (from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/vartype-function)

```
vbEmpty             0       Empty (uninitialized)
vbNull              1       Null (no valid data)
vbInteger           2       Integer
vbLong              3       Long integer
vbSingle            4       Single-precision floating-point number
vbDouble            5       Double-precision floating-point number
vbCurrency          6       Currency value
vbDate              7       Date value
vbString            8       String
vbObject            9       Object
vbError             10      Error value
vbBoolean           11      Boolean value
vbVariant           12      Variant (used only with arrays of variants)
vbDataObject        13      A data access object
vbDecimal           14      Decimal value
vbByte              17      Byte value
vbLongLong          20      LongLong integer (valid on 64-bit platforms only)
vbUserDefinedType   36      Variants that contain user-defined types
vbArray             8192    Array
```

Comment: This looks like what I am trying to get, but running this I get an error:        Line 19,   Char 9,  Error  Name redefined, Code 800A0411

Comment: Name redefined means you are redeclaring something thats already been dimmed make sure you move your Dim statement earlier and just reuse the variable name.  Check to see what variable you are declaring on Line 19

Comment: I have revised the script to add the above and  runs now without error.  However I do not get "Not Applicable" in any column of the data table-still getting Null.

Comment: On the machines that you get Null data, do some columns have data but others don't or is it completely null.  The count check in the example above will return not applicable for all properties if WMI returns 0 instances of TPM but if it returns a TPM instance with a few null properties that will be returned as null you would need to implement something to confirm null values on a valid object.

Comment: If there is null because TPM is not turned on, all columns are null.  On pcs where TPM is turned on, there is data in each column.  Do not see how to attach a screen shot for clarity.

Comment: Maybe try adding the function i've included above.  If its return an instance with null values this should take care of returning a default value.

Comment: I have changed the script to include the above.   On a pc where TPM is not on, I still get nulls and now, on a pc that used to have data for each row is also showing null.  This may be my lack of understanding all this.  When I run anSQL  query, a pc that does not have any TPM  does not display in the results unless I use a right join.  Then in the results  that are displayed in TOAD, I get a null.  I may have mislead you when I gave that as a value. If I run a wmic from cmd prompt, I either get True or False if TPM on in BIOS, or if not enabled, then No Instance(s) Available.

Comment: Okay, so based on that information the original solution should be all you need.  Is this creating new rows every time the script is run.  Is there a timestamp in your SQL table?  Maybe you can filter by max time stamp for each distinct resource.

Comment: The original  did not enter anything for the pc  without tpm in the database. In order to see the pc name in the data results, I had to use right join.  That  allows any pc with nulls in any column to be in the dataset. When an inventory is run, the results overwrite the existing data so there is no need for a timestamp to find comparisons.  None of what we have done has put 'not applicable'.  In the last attempt it 'removed all data for a pc that had all the tpm info. It seems that something is not matching, therefore the results are empty and that is what then get written to the db.

Comment: This is a guess since I do not know  scripting.  When I run a wmic query against a pc where tpm is not 'on', there are no results and no value names. Nothing- just the message "No Instance(s) Available.".  In what you suggested, if If colItems.Count > 0 Then  do something or else.  But since there are no items at all, would this then skip everything and therefore not  write 'Not Applicable' ?

Comment: your  colItems is an object that has all the instances returned from your query.  the Win32_Tpm is a singleton class so it can only ever have 0 or 1 results in it.  By doing  colItems.Count > 0 means if it finds that instance then write the values to your database.  Else (so if that condition is not met) create a row with "Not Applicable" (as a hard coded value) for all its columns.  As an aside, your original question has a typo i think?  you have a line that says "Sim objDCInstance" is that actually "Dim objDCInstance" in your script?

Comment: That would be a typo. Not sure at this point why not getting expected results. Neither script output Not Applicable for the pc where TPM is not active. Running wmic /namespace:\\root\cimv2\security\microsofttpm path win32_tpm get IsActivated_InitialValue gives me No Instance(s) Available. So is that not meeting the statement --"colItems.Count > 0 "? therefore the test fails and script completes without writing Not Applicable?

Comment: If wmic results state "No Instance(s) Available" then it would take the path to the ELSE condition in the script which will set all fields to "Not Applicable".  On computers where wmic gives you instances, the script would take the path of colItems.Count > 0 and setfield will be each of the properties as you have listed such as IsActivated_InitialValue and IsEnabled_InitialValue

Comment: Thanks for all your help. At this point I am at a dead end.  Cannot get the script to output 'Not Applicable".

Comment: Running WMIC to check for the existence is not part of the vb script.  That just shows that the Win32_Tpm does not exist. In the actual script, the error comes before it even gets to : Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_Tpm", "WQL", wbemFlagReturnImmediately + wbemFlagForwardOnly)
The error is at: GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\CIMV2\Security\MicrosoftTpm")  VBSEdit shows error:Line 8 Col 1 Error (null) CODE 80041003 Source (null)

Comment: From your original code, line 8 references your Altiris.AeXNSEvent.  Unless you've changed your code around a bit since the original post.  I would look into if that object exists and is functional on the machines you are running.  If the WMI query is whats crashing in your script, you can wrap put "On Error Resume Next" before the query to disable exiting on error then "On Error Goto 0" after your query to re-enable the exit on error.  This should allow your code to pass down.

Comment: I have removed all references to Altiris. I was given another 'try this' from Symantec.  Now, neither pc shows any output in the task status in Altiris. Also, in vbsedit, running the script on the pc that does have TPM Enabled and showed the data originally, I get pop up box "Error connecting to", presumably from line 5 (If Err.number <> 0 Then WScript.Echo "Error connecting to: " & strComputer). I seem to be going backwards here.  Unable to post script as message says too long. Is there another way?

Comment: You can edit your original post and add any additional information.  Its common practice on stackoverflow to keep your original post (script and all) and just start adding information below it by writing "EDIT: <additional information for the edit>".

Comment: Apparently I have hit a wall with this as neither suggestions here or on Symantec have dealt with the issue of--- where the pc does not have TPM, the script is not writing anything-- the else  statement seems to be bypassed.

Comment: I've updated my answer based on your latest post edit.  Take a look and let me know if it helps

Comment: Output from running : the error is -2147217406 = WBEM_E_NOT_FOUND - Object cannot be found.  VarType: 0, Setting Not Applicable when necessary

Comment: That makes sense... the instance does not exist but the namespace and class is there.  So the output from my script is a wscript.echo that "Setting Not Applicable when necessary" (the verbiage from your script).  So where are you stuck now?  This logic handles the issue

Comment: After Wscript echo, it needs to write 'Not Applicable'   to the database fields 1 thru 7. Can't put code here due to character limitation of this message box